# A protocol for honest compromise

Tags: cr.crypto-security, gt.game-theory

This question did not originate in my research, but I think it's interesting. It is somewhat underspecified. I'd be interested in an example in any particular case.

We have $n$ parties that between them must choose a value $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Each party has a preferred value $p_i$ for $x$, but we must find a compromise. Let's say we want the mean of the preferences.

Now, anybody who has been involved in politics will know that taking the middle way between *stated* preferences can be gamed by stating a more extreme position than the actual preference, so that the mean lands closer to it. Is there a protocol that lets us find (an approximation to) the mean of the true preferences?

As an analogy, one can take the second-price auction, where everybody is best served by bidding their true valuation.

Comment: The paper "Mechanism Design via Differential Privacy" gives a approximately truthful mechanism for auctions which also provides some sort of resilience against coalitions as a biproduct of differential privacy. The mechanism they provide is called the Exponential Mechanism and depends generally on sampling, but is not necessarily efficient. I am not sure if this is what you want nor if it helps but it looks related.

Comment: Link: http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=65075

Comment: From that paper I have learnt that this kind of "reverse game theory", where one is designing a game in order to encourage a certain strategies, is called "mechanism design". Perhaps a mechanism-design tag would be useful, but I don't have enough rep to create it.

Comment: It seems to be well known in economics that if you do this with the *median* instead of mean, everybody maximizes their payoff by being honest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a trivial protocol whose expected value is the correct mean: everybody announces their preference, and one is chosen at random. No player (acting alone) can do better than to announce their true preference. I haven't yet looked at the collusion-resistance of this protocol (I would guess it depends on the exact payoff functions).